# Extracting only some coefficients for the logistic regression model and its plot

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, coefficients

```r
sample_data = read.table("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/db.txt",
                         header=TRUE, sep=";")
head(sample_data)
model = glm(Y~0+X1+X2+X3,family=binomial,data=sample_data)
summary(model)
exp(coef(model ))
exp(cbind(OR = coef(model ), confint(model )))
```

I have the above sample data on logistic regression with categorical predictor
I try the above code i get the following  output,

```r
            OR       2.5 %     97.5 %
X1  1.67639337 1.352583976 2.09856514
X2  1.23377720 1.071959330 1.42496949
X3A 0.01157565 0.001429430 0.08726854
X3B 0.06627849 0.008011818 0.54419759
X3C 0.01118084 0.001339984 0.08721028
X3D 0.01254032 0.001545240 0.09539880
X3E 0.10654454 0.013141540 0.87369972
```

but I am wondering how to extract OR and  CI only for factors. My
desired output will be:

```r
 OR       2.5 %     97.5 %
X3A 0.01157565 0.001429430 0.08726854
X3B 0.06627849 0.008011818 0.54419759
X3C 0.01118084 0.001339984 0.08721028
X3D 0.01254032 0.001545240 0.09539880
X3E 0.10654454 0.013141540 0.87369972
```

Can any one help me the code to extract it?
additionally I want to plot the above OR with confidence interval for
the extracted one.
Can you also help me the code with plot,or box plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out the rows that are the same as variable names in your data frame, since those row names with factor levels appended will not match:

```r
result <- exp(cbind(OR = coef(model ), confint(model )))

result[!rownames(result) %in% names(sample_data),]
#>             OR       2.5 %     97.5 %
#> X3A 0.01157565 0.001429430 0.08726854
#> X3B 0.06627849 0.008011818 0.54419759
#> X3C 0.01118084 0.001339984 0.08721028
#> X3D 0.01254032 0.001545240 0.09539880
#> X3E 0.10654454 0.013141540 0.87369972
```

To extract the necessary rows and plot them, the full reproducible code would be:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample_data <-  read.table("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/db.txt",
                           header = TRUE, sep = ";")

model <- glm(Y ~ 0 + X1 + X2 + X3,family = binomial, data = sample_data)
result <- exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...

result %>% 
  as.data.frame(check.names = FALSE) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Variable") %>%
  filter(!Variable %in% names(sample_data)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = OR, y = Variable)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = 2) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = `2.5 %`, xmax = `97.5 %`), height = 0.1) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_x_log10(name = "Odds ratio (log scale)") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, using `broom` to extract the coefficients, `dplyr::filter` to select the terms you want, and `dwplot` to plot.

```r
library(broom)
library(dotwhisker)
library(dplyr)
tt <- (tidy(model, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)
   |> filter(stringr::str_detect(term, "^X3"))
)
dwplot(tt)
```

In addition, I would suggest:

```r
library(ggplot2)
dwplot(tt) + scale_x_log10() + geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 2) +
   labs(x="Odds ratio")
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all but the first 2 rows, use a negative index on the rows.
I will also coerce to `data.frame` and add an `id`, it will be needed to plot the confidence intervals.

```
ORCI <- exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))[-(1:2), ]
ORCI <- cbind.data.frame(ORCI, id = row.names(ORCI))
```